# Elasticsearch multiple suggestions with more advanced cases like matching prefix in the middle of a sentence

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, prefix, n-gram, elasticsearch-7

My use case : I have a search bar when the user can type his query. I want to show multiple types of search suggestions to the user in addition to a regular query suggestion. For example, in the screenshot below, as you can see in this screenshot, you can see there are company sector, companies, and schools suggestions.

[image]

This is currently implemented using [completion suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester) and the following mappings (this is code from our Ruby implementation, but I believe you should be able to understand it easily)

```rb
{
  _source: '',
  suggest: {
    text: query_from_the_user, # User query like "sec" to find "security" related matches 
    'school_names': {
      completion: {
        field: 'school_names_suggest',
      },
    },
    'companies': {
      completion: {
        field: 'company_name.suggest',
      },
    },
    'sectors': {
      completion: {
        field: sector_field_based_on_current_language(I18n.locale),
             # uses 'company_sector.french.suggest' when the user browses in french
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Here are my mappings (this is written in Ruby as but I believe it shouldn't be too hard to mentally convert this to Elasticsearch JSON config

```rb
indexes :company_name, type: 'text' do
  indexes :suggest, type: 'completion'
end
indexes :company_sector, type: 'object' do
  indexes :french, type: 'text' do
    indexes :suggest, type: 'completion'
  end
  indexes :english, type: 'text' do
    indexes :suggest, type: 'completion'
  end
end
indexes :school_names_suggest, type: 'completion'
# sample Indexed JSON 
{ 
  company_name: "Christian Dior Couture",
  company_sector: {
    english: 'Milk sector',
    french: 'Secteur laitier'
  },
  school_names_suggest: ['Télécom ParisTech', 'Ecole Centrale Paris']
}
```

The problem is the suggestion is not powerful enough and cannot autocomplete based on the middle of a sentence and provide additional results even after a perfect match. Here are some scenarios that I need to capture with my ES implementation

#### CASE 1 - Matching by prefix in the middle of a sentence

```
# documents
[{ company_name: "Christian Dior Couture" }]
# => A search term "Dior" should return this document because it matches by prefix on the second word
```

#### CASE 2 - Provide results even after a perfect match

```
# documents
[
  { company_name: "Crédit Agricole" },
  { company_name: "Crédit Agricole Pyrénées Gascogne" },
]
# => A search term "Crédit Agricole" should return both documents (using the current implementation it only returns "Crédit Agricole"
```

Can I implement this using suggesters in Elasticsearch ? Or do I need to fall back to multiple `search` that would take advantage of the new `search-as-you-type` data type using a `query` as mentionned [in the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-as-you-type.html) ?

I am using elasticsearch 7.1 on AWS and the Ruby driver (gem `elasticsearch-7.3.0`)